# Why won't my images draw instantly? HTML5 canvas

Tags: arrays, html, image, loops, canvas

So, here's my code

```
function drawLocations(){
    var i = 2;
    var storedData = sessionStorage.locations;
    locations = JSON.parse(storedData);
    while(i<25){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = locations[i];
        ctx.drawImage(img,i*20,canvas.height-40);
    i++;
    }
}
```

When I print the sessionStorage.locations variable in the console it prints an array that looks like this...

```
["","","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png","spike.png"]
```

which is exactly what it is supposed to do. I stringified the array with JSON so storing an array in sessionStorage is not the problem. The problem is that when I run my code it take about 30 seconds to draw all the spikes on the screen. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving your images time to load before trying to drawImage them.

You must use .onload which gets called after your image has fully loaded.

Here's an example using image.onload:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yjS2L/

[image]

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/picketFence.jpg";
function start(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        ctx.drawImage(img,i*99,canvas.height-img.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add the onload function it says img is not defined.

Comment: You're not still creating `new Image()` in a while loop are you?  Since you're just using one image, just load that image once (as in my answer) then use a for-loop to display that image across the canvas.